# How to extend an object in Scala with an abstract class with constructor?

Tags: scala

How to extend an object in Scala with an abstract class that has a constructor, and apply method of the object returns the object as subtype of the abstract?

for example :

```
abstract class AbstractResource(amount:Int) {
    val amount:Int
    def getAmount = amount
}


case object Wood extends AbstractResource{
    def apply(amount: Int) = {
        // something that returns the subtype
   }
}
```

I think a good solution is:

```
abstract class AbstractResource {
    val amount: Int = 0

    def getAmount = amount
}


case object Wood extends AbstractResource {
    def apply(quantity: Int) = {
        new AbstractResource {
            override val amount = quantity
        }
    }
}
```

But my problem is I can't edit AbstractResource

Comment: Are you sure you don't want `case class Wood(amount: Int) extends AbstractResource(amount)`?

Comment: @TobiasBrandt Yes I don't want

Comment: Why does `Wood` have to extend `AbstractResource`? Note that the thing `Wood#apply` is returning is not of type `Wood`.

Comment: @TobiasBrandt Because I need a set that contains all subtypes of the AbstractResource

Comment: Well, then `Wood` _must_ call the constructor of `AbstractResource`. I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Note that your first definition of `AbstractResource` is not valid: `error: amount is already defined as value amount`.

Comment: @senia, Yes, my first definition is a prototype, that I want to approach

Comment: @Pooya How is this set of AbstractResource subtypes to be used? I have doubts that even your prototype solution is likely to achieve what you think it does, let alone what you actually need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have no idea why should `Wood` extend `AbstractResource`, but this works:

```
class AbstractResource(val amount:Int) {
  def getAmount = amount
}

case object Wood extends AbstractResource(0) {
  def apply(amount: Int) = {
    new AbstractResource(amount)
  }
}
```

Comment: I think I should use a middle abstract class

Comment: @Pooya what is a middle abstract class?