# Case object extending class with constructor in Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming, abstract-data-type

I am a beginner in Scala and was playing around to learn more about Abstract data types. I defined the following definition to replicate Option type:

```
sealed abstract class Maybe[+A](x:A)
case object Nothing extends Maybe[Nothing](Nothing)
case class Just[A](x:A) extends Maybe[A](x)
```

But I encountered the following error.

```
found   : Nothing.type
required: Nothing
    case object Nothing extends Maybe[Nothing](Nothing)
```

How do I pass `Nothing` instead of `Nothing.type`?

I referred to the following question for hints:
[How to extend an object in Scala with an abstract class with constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18097753/how-to-extend-an-object-in-scala-with-an-abstract-class-with-constructor), but it was not helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit of clarification for Assaf Mendelson's answer, but it's too big for a comment.

```
case object Nothing extends Maybe[Nothing](Nothing)
```

Scala has separate namespaces for types and values. `Nothing` in `case object Nothing` is a value. `Nothing` in `Maybe[Nothing]` is a type. Since you didn't define a type called `Nothing`, it refers to the automatically imported `scala.Nothing` and you must pass a value of this type as an argument. By definition it has no values but e.g. `case object Nothing extends Maybe[Nothing](throw new Exception)` would compile, as the type of `throw` expressions is `Nothing`. Instead you pass the value `Nothing`, i.e. the same `case object` you are defining; its type is written as `Nothing.type`.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe more like this. Your Nothing shouldnt have a value, just the type. Also people usually use traits instead of abstract classes.

```
sealed trait Maybe[+A]
case object None extends Maybe[Nothing]
case class Just[A](x:A) extends Maybe[A]
```

You probably shouldnt create your own Nothing, thats going to be confusing, you will confuse yourself and the compiler about if you are referring to your one, or the one at the bottom of the type hierarchy.

Comment: Creating a different `None` might also cause some confusion, but it's certainly better than defining a 2nd `Nothing`.

Comment: Actually, you can't define a 2nd `Nothing`.

Comment: Thank you. But how can we use case object when extending a class with parameterized constructor? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Stephen, the correct way to do this would be not to have trait and not an abstract class, however, I thought it might be informative to explain why the current methodology fails and how to fix it.

The main issue is with this line:

```
 case object Nothing extends Maybe[Nothing](Nothing)
```

First thing (as mentioned) you shouldn't call your object Nothing. Secondly, you set the object to extend Maybe[Nothing]. Nothing can't have any actual values so you can't use it as an object. Also, you can't use the object itself as the constructor parameter because that would cause a cyclic behavior.

What you need is to have a bottom type (i.e. a type which all A have in common) and an object of that type. Nothing is a bottom type but has no objects.

A possible solution is to limit yourself to AnyRef (i.e. nullable objects) and use the Null bottom type which has a valid object (null):

```
 sealed abstract class Maybe[+A <: AnyRef](x:A)
 case object None extends Maybe[Null](null)
```

Answer (score 0):

> How do I pass Nothing instead of Nothing.type?

It seems like there is no way to do so.
As it says at http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.9.1/scala/Nothing.html:

> there exist no instances of this type.